# October CMS 2.2.4 - Backend: Invalid Security Token

Tags: octobercms

I'm running October CMS v2.2.4 on a dedicated managed server with Cloudways. I keep getting "Invalid Security Token" every few minutes after saving any changes in the Backend and I'm forced to refresh the page, redo my changes, then save again. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions:

1. Give 775 permission to **storage** directory. The server may not have permission to create a session file.
2. Change session driver from `file` to `database` so the session will manage by the database instead.

```
SESSION_DRIVER=database
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused due to CSRF protection and Session.

1. Check session.php file and increase session lifetime

`'lifetime' => 120,`

2. Then run `php artisan cache:clear`
3. Check for URL if it is running on https:// rather than http://
4. If all of above points didn't help it could be a server configuration issue.

LukeTowers Explained this issue in following
https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/3266